# TypeScript `not assignable` to seemingly identical type

Tags: typescript, typeerror

In the following code, TypeScript gives an error saying `Type '(...params: P) => O' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'` on the obj[key] assignment although it seems to me like it should be fine.

```
type Function <P extends any[], O> = (...params: P) => O

type Z <K extends string | number | symbol, P extends any[], O> = {
  [key in K]: Function<P, O>
}

/**
 * Wraps an existing function to call the given function with the result.
 * The original function is functionally identical.
 */
export function consumer <
  T extends Z<K, P, O>,
  K extends keyof T,
  P extends any[],
  O
> (
  obj: T,
  key: K,
  consume: Function<[O], void>
) {
  obj[key] = (...params: P) => {
    const value = obj[key](...params)
    consume(value)
    return value
  }
}
```